# Sub Dir Not Created In php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a sub directory in PHP, but it's created in the root directory, not in the destination directory:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $dirName = $_POST['dirname'];
    $path = $_POST['PATH'];
    $dir = "../apps/Assamese_Songs/".$path."/" .$dirName."/";
    if (mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
        //header('Location: folder_manager.php');
    }
}
```

Every time the directory is created in `Assamese_Songs` directory, but I want it created in `$path`.

Comment: Check if $path is set or not.

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Please show the value of `$path`.